# Hurricane symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, symbols, packages, icon

There were hyperuragans mentioned on an Italian television channel.

Does any of you know if there is a specific package in `LaTeX`, or fonts that reproduce hurricane symbols with numbers?

[image: https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/set-hurricane-scale-icons-symbolic-260nw-712052398.jpg]

The image is taken from https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/set-hurricane-scale-icons-symbolic-260nw-712052398.jpg.

Comment: In general http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf is a good source for symbols, but I cannot find something close. How exact do you want it, because with the shading it looks like a job for `pgf` and `tikz`.

Comment: @TobiBS Thank you very much, but there is no symbol of hurrican into the comprehensive pdf.

Comment: This is, why I was asking what exactly you are looking for. A black/white representation of it, or an exact color copy including the shades?

Comment: @TobiBS I have put an image example: for me is not important if it is black/white or with colors and shadows.

Comment: I added an answer with `TikZ` in two variants, a simple b/w and a colored version with opacity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a CYCLONE emoji (U+1F300) which you could exploit in order to obtain the result intended. Unfortunately it only works with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX as it need a proper emoji font (I chose [Symbola](https://packages.debian.org/sid/fonts-symbola)).

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
%xelatex does fine, too
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newfontfamily\emojii{Symbola}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\hurricane}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myloop{(\x-1)*72}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mycolor{\x/#1}
    \node[rotate=\myloop,opacity=\mycolor] at (0,0) {{\emojii\Huge{\color{red} }}};%
}
\node[circle,fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (0,0) {\scriptsize{\textsf{\color{red}#1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\hurricane{5}\hurricane{4}\hurricane{3}\hurricane{2}\hurricane{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the same result with [Open Sans Emoji](https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji):
[image]

(The grey spots are due to my broken ImageMagick, sorry. They work fine in PDF output)

Comment: Very very good your your precious contributes. Where can I find the font Symbola? Excellent answer.

Comment: In Linux (Ubuntu) you can directly download it from a repo. Otherwise, you can Google it. I'll share a link soon, I'm at lunch ☺

Comment: Have a good dinner then... thanks to you.

Comment: I've just added links to Symbola and Open Sans Emoji

Answer (score 5):

### Colored version

And a colored version, the `\foreach` can and should be tweaked for sure, but it is closer to what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\drawSwoosh}[3]{\begin{scope}[rotate=#1]\fill[fill=#2,opacity=#3] (0:1) .. controls (1,-.6) and (1,-1) .. (-100:2.5) .. controls (-85:1.4) and (-90:1.2) .. (-90:1) arc (-90:-360:1);\end{scope}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \angle/\opaquness in {0/1, 180/1}
    \drawSwoosh{\angle}{green}{\opaquness}
    \node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle/\opaquness in {0/0.5, 180/0.5, 90/1, 270/1}
    \drawSwoosh{\angle}{yellow}{\opaquness}
    \node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle/\opaquness in {0/0.25, 180/0.25, 60/0.5, 240/0.5, 120/1, 300/1}
\drawSwoosh{\angle}{orange}{\opaquness}
\node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle/\opaquness in {0/0.125, 180/0.125, 45/0.25, 225/0.25, 90/0.5, 270/0.5, 135/1, 315/1}
\drawSwoosh{\angle}{red}{\opaquness}
\node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle/\opaquness in {0/0.0625, 180/0.0625, 36/0.125, 216/0.125, 72/0.25, 252/0.25, 108/0.5, 288/0.5, 144/1, 324/1}
\drawSwoosh{\angle}{magenta}{\opaquness}
\node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### Original answer

A starting point with `TikZ` could be the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\drawSwoosh}[1]{\begin{scope}[rotate=#1]\draw[fill=black] (0:1) .. controls (1,-.6) and (1,-1) .. (-100:2.5) .. controls (-85:1.4) and (-90:1.2) .. (-90:1) arc (-90:-360:1);\end{scope}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \angle in {0,180,...,359}
    \drawSwoosh{\angle}
    \node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,...,359}
    \drawSwoosh{\angle}
    \node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle in {0,72,...,359}
\drawSwoosh{\angle}
\node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle in {0,45,...,359}
\drawSwoosh{\angle}
\node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle in {0,36,...,359}
\drawSwoosh{\angle}
\node[fill=white,circle] at (0,0) {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice but shouldn't symbol 3 have six points?

Comment: @albert You mean according to the image from Sebastiano or based on the code? With 72° between the rotations you have 360°/72°=5 positions.

Comment: With 72 degrees you have indeed 5 points but on the given image I see 6 points so 60 degrees. So probably changing `\foreach \angle in {0,72,...,359}`  into `\foreach \angle in {0,60,...,359}` should be sufficient.

Comment: @albert Yes it you want 6 points you should use your change. But my answer does not resemble the whole set of symbols from the question, just a subset to show the trick. You can also add the different coloring, etc.

Comment: @TobiBS Thank you very much for your lot effort with tikz. My idea was only to use icons or symbol. But I thank you very much...also more than of your answer.

Comment: Well the other answer uses TikZ, too. If you graphically like this approach, you can wrap it in a single command, just as the answer from JairoADelRio.

Comment: @TobiBS I'm thanking you again :-)